# Copy a row of data from one sheet to another automatically in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Edit
Hello, 
Trying to copy a row of data from a roster on a sheet into a new sheet when a cell states Line 1 
ie When i type Line 1 etc i want excel to automatically take the row of data for Line 1 on my data sheet and insert it into the target row, cannot use VBA 
Appreciate help, i am a beginner

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in A1 to E2 in Sheet1 and your formula in Sheet2:

```
=IF(Sheet2!A2="","",INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$E$2,Sheet2!A2,COLUMN(Sheet2!B2)-1))
```

Now type into cell A2 in Sheet2 the row you want the data from in Sheet1. Drag the formula to the right or down by clicking on the lower right corner.